# Cond definition in scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, eval, conditional-statements, racket

This will be an easy question I guess but I need it.I am making a simulator game in scheme(Dr Racket)and I want to change how cond works.But to change the thing cond does I need to know the definition of cond and I could not find it in Dr racket.Can someone give the definition of cond in scheme?

Comment: I think you'd be better off writing your own "cond-like" macro than redefining `cond` itself.

Comment: "I want to change how cond works"  Stack Overflow is generally a better fit for specific technical questions.  What different behavior are you looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Racket definition of `cond` is in `collects/racket/private/cond.rkt`. It's written using low-level syntax object operations, not using either `syntax-rules` nor `syntax-case`, so unless you know syntax objects very well, it won't be readable to you.

As an alternative starting place for your customised `cond`, one definition of `cond` is the reference implementation given in [SRFI 61](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-61/srfi-61.html). It is succinct and is one of the best implementations of `cond` I've seen:

```
(define-syntax cond
  (syntax-rules (=> else)

    ((cond (else else1 else2 ...))
     ;; The (if #t (begin ...)) wrapper ensures that there may be no
     ;; internal definitions in the body of the clause.  R5RS mandates
     ;; this in text (by referring to each subform of the clauses as
     ;; <expression>) but not in its reference implementation of cond,
     ;; which just expands to (begin ...) with no (if #t ...) wrapper.
     (if #t (begin else1 else2 ...)))

    ((cond (test => receiver) more-clause ...)
     (let ((t test))
       (cond/maybe-more t
                        (receiver t)
                        more-clause ...)))

    ((cond (generator guard => receiver) more-clause ...)
     (call-with-values (lambda () generator)
       (lambda t
         (cond/maybe-more (apply guard    t)
                          (apply receiver t)
                          more-clause ...))))

    ((cond (test) more-clause ...)
     (let ((t test))
       (cond/maybe-more t t more-clause ...)))

    ((cond (test body1 body2 ...) more-clause ...)
     (cond/maybe-more test
                      (begin body1 body2 ...)
                      more-clause ...))))

(define-syntax cond/maybe-more
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((cond/maybe-more test consequent)
     (if test
         consequent))
    ((cond/maybe-more test consequent clause ...)
     (if test
         consequent
         (cond clause ...)))))
```

(As molbdnilo says, though, please call your version something other than `cond` to avoid confusion.)

Answer (score 1):

r5rs describes cond here: [http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.1](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%25_sec_4.2.1)

You would normally implement it as a macro.

Comment: The reference implementation of `cond` is also in R5RS: http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-10.html#%_sec_7.3